# "The more the foreign worker immerse themselves in the local culture, the more realistic a view they develop of that culture."

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, sentence-choice

Which one should I use?

> The more the foreign worker immerse themselves in the local culture, the more realistic a view they develop of that culture.

> The more the foreign worker is immersed in the local culture, the more realistic a view is developed towards that culture.[image]
> https://www.globalcognition.org/what-is-cultural-sensitivity/

Comment: The first example is NOT grammatical. The second fails to tell the reader who is developing the more realistic view. I wouldn't use either.

Comment: It may be that "the develop" is a typo for "they develop".

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not grammatical.

Try these:

> The more that foreign workers are involved in the local culture, the
> more realistic their views will be of that culture.
>
> Foreign workers develop realistic views of local culture the more
> they share in its life.
>
> Immersion in local culture develops realistic views in foreign
> workers.
>
> A foreign worker will develop realistic cultural views by being
> immersed in the life of the community.
>
> If foreign workers are immersed in local life, they will develop
> realistic views of that culture.
>
> Immersion in local life develops realistic views in foreign workers.
>
> For foreign workers, involvement in local life goes hand-in-hand with
> having realistic opinions of their adopted culture.
>
> Immersion in local life develops realistic opinions in foreign workers.

So, what was problematic about the example sentences?  Subject-verb agreement was one problem.

The other problem comes from the word *immersion*. Think of it this way:

> The more drowned a person is, the worse.

One is either immersed or not immersed.